# Highstock: TypeError: elem[setAttribute] is not a function

Tags: svg, highcharts

I have the Highstock inside an SVG and elem is an object with { 0 = , context =  length = 1 }, which is the SVG  element i want to place the Highstock inside.

Error happens in highstock.src.js line 289 (Highstock JS v1.3.2 (2013-06-05))

Comment: Recreate issue on jsFiddle, please.

Comment: I have solved it by using a foreignObject inside the main SVG. But it would be nicer to be able to insert a HighChart directly into a SVG.